# Conversion of number to Indian rupees format is not working in my htmlto pdf js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I need to convert a number into a string in [Indian rupees format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system), but this function in my nodemodules js file is not working i am using in expression:

```
{{Math.abs(-485698512).toLocaleString("en-IN", { maximumFractionDigits:0})}};
```

I want the answer in this format: *48,56,98,512*

Comment: You say your function is not working. Can you [edit] your question to show what it is giving? That would help understand how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

var num =485698512; var cuv=num.toString(); var lastThree =cuv.substring(cuv.length-3); var otherNumbers = cuv.substring(0,cuv.length-3); if(otherNumbers != '') lastThree = ',' + lastThree; var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree; alert(res);

answer is =48,56,98,512